# How do I install Ubuntu 12.04 PPC on a PowerPC G4 from commands line or fix the graphical mode?

Tags: system-installation, powerpc

I recently got a Mac as a gift, a PowerPC G4 , which has 1GB of RAM but came with no optical drive or hard drive. So I put a dvd burner and a hard drive of 40 GB I got. Then download an iso of Ubuntu 12.04 for PowerPC and burned onto a CD. I'm trying to install from Open Firmware ( as I haven't a Mac keyboard, I use one standard ) .

Finally, the Installation CD boots, but on live mode and after the Ubuntu 12.04 screen I get a message that there is a problem with my graphics adapter but I can continue with minimal graphics and give me the command line .

My question is that how do I install through a text or if there is any way to fix this problem to run the graphical mode and so can continue the installation of Ubuntu, and if once installed Ubuntu the problem will be fixed or what?

I would appreciate if you help me , as I mentioned before, there is almost nothing of Ubuntu but I think it will be easier than trying to get the Mac OS X proper . Spend good.

Adding information: there is not a BIOS screen, I use OpenFirmware (Alt+Windows+f+o) to give the instruction to boot from the CD, then shows a menu with the options live, nosplash, driverupdates, etc. I just press enter and set as default "live" and shows the Ubuntu's loading screen (the dots changing from white to red and back) and then shows the messsage that there is a problem with my adapter, display and input device. I click OK and shows a menu with 4 options: run in low-graphical mode, reconfigure graphics, troubleshoot the error or exit to login prompt. I have chossed all this one with the same results: the screen changes to a kind of terminal with ubuntu@ubuntu~>_

Comment: that screen with the keyboard is not displayed, how can i do? i just see the Ubuntu's loading screen and then i receive the message that my adapter and input device is not correctly detected and then the graphical mode is gone and show a kind of console.

Answer (score 0):

If you boot ubuntu from a livecd right after the bios splash screen you will get a purple screen with a keyboard logo at the bottom. Press any key at that moment to access a menu. Select your language with the arrow keys, press enter and you will see a menu. If you press the F6 key, a menu at the bottom will open allowing you to set kernel options with the space bar or enter key. Pick the option NOMODESET. You can close the menu with escape key and resume booting by selecting the option “try ubuntu without installing” (please note that session does allow you to install ubuntu once you found the kernel options cured your problem).